# ionic 3 tabs width to avoid entire horizontal space

Tags: css, ionic3

i am using ionic-tabs component and trying to make the tab bar width just enough to show contents rather taking the entire space.

I don't see a sass variable to control it. all the variables are to control text and color related items.

How can i set the max height and widht for the ion-tabs ?

What I am aiming to look them like

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vv9vjjk2ym3iacb/Screenshot%202017-10-23%2014.10.27.png?dl=0

instead of 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj1s1tp3xd8wbub/Screenshot%202017-10-23%2014.11.00.png?dl=0

Comment: What about `$tabs-ios-tab-max-width`? Or directly overriding in your scss: `.tab-button { max-width: 20px; }`.

Comment: I used direct overriding and this worked! thanks! however the same didnt work for max-height. any ideas?

Comment: Depending on if your tabs contain text, an icon or both the height is controlled by different `min-height` values (e.g. icon and text is 5.6rem), by overriding `min-height` you can control this yourself: `.tab-button { min-height: 2rem; }`.